# Contacts recall with mult numbers

Tags: iphone, caller-id

How do find out which number you dialed after the call when a contact has multiple numbers associated with it. On an iphone

Answer (score 1):

Go to the *Phone* app and tap on the *Recents* tab.  You'll see incoming and outgoing calls there.  The outgoing calls have a little phone handset icon with an arrow going up.  When you click on the information icon, the 'i' inside the circle, you'll see details of the call.  It will also say 'incoming' or 'outgoing'.

Comment: If I go into Recents tab in the Phone app, I see the blue circle. When I touch it, it brings up the contact of the person who called, but it doesn't say which of the 3 numbers I have for them (home, work, cell) they called from. Can you be more specific, please?

Comment: On the *Recents* tab under the contact name will be the label of the specific number called. For instance, if a contact has a *Mobile* and *Home* number in the Contact and I called the *Mobile*, it will say 'mobile' under the name. Tap on the Info circle and see the contact info and the number associated with 'mobile'.

Comment: Got it! Thank you for your patience. I understand now.

Comment: NP, I should've been more clear in my answer.